# Erlang FFI into ImageMagick

Tags: c, erlang

This is a short program meant to give me an Erlang hook into the ImageMagick FFI for performance reasons.

All comments welcome, but specifically

- my C experience is minimal, bordering on nonexistent, so I would particularly appreciate hints in that area.
- the setup here is one of a long-running process that will be accepting many requests, so if you see any memory leaks point them out (for bonus points, try to explain why they're happening in a way that will let me recognize similar situations in the future)

At a high level, what's happening is that the Erlang process is spawning off a new OS process of the C program and grabbing its `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` for communication purposes. When a request for thumbnailing comes in, the Erlang process sends its pathname to the C process then waits for one of three responses (`ok`, `could_not_read` or `could_not_write`) encoded as an integer. If successful, an image called "thumbnail.png" is created in the same directory as the incoming file.

Erlang part first:

```erlang
-module(wand).
-export([start/0, stop/0, restart/0]).
-export([thumbnail/1]).

start() ->
    spawn(fun() ->
          register(wand, self()),
          process_flag(trap_exit, true),
          Port = open_port({spawn, "./wand"}, [{packet, 2}]),
          loop(Port)
      end).

stop() -> wand ! stop.

restart() -> stop(), start().

thumbnail(Filename) ->
    call_port(Filename).

call_port(Msg) ->
    wand ! {call, self(), Msg},
    receive
    {wand, Result} ->
        Result
    end.

loop(Port) ->
    receive
    {call, Caller, Msg} ->
        Port ! {self(), {command, Msg}},
        receive
        {Port, {data, Data}} ->
            Caller ! {wand, decode(Data)}    
        end,
        loop(Port);
    stop ->
        Port ! {self(), close},
        receive
        {Port, closed} ->
            exit(normal)
        end;
    {'EXIT', Port, Reason} ->
        exit({port_terminated, Reason})
    end.

decode([0]) -> {ok, 0};
decode([1]) -> {error, could_not_read};
decode([2]) -> {error, could_not_write}.
```

Next, the read/write functions to handle length headers:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

int read_cmd(byte *buff);
int write_cmd(byte *buff, int len);
int read_exact(byte *buff, int len);
int write_exact(byte *buff, int len);

int read_cmd(byte *buff) {
  int len;
  if (read_exact(buff, 2) != 2) {
    return(-1);
  }
  len = (buff[0] << 8) | buff[1];
  return read_exact(buff, len);
}

int write_cmd(byte *buff, int len) {
  byte li;
  li = (len >> 8) & 0xff;
  write_exact(&li, 1);

  li = len & 0xff;
  write_exact(&li, 1);

  return write_exact(buff, len);
}

int read_exact(byte *buff, int len){
  int i, got=0;
  do {
    if ((i = read(0, buff+got, len-got)) <= 0) {
      return(i);
    }
    got +=i;
  } while (got<len);
  buff[len] = '\0';
  return(len);
}

int write_exact(byte *buff, int len) {
  int i, wrote = 0;
  do {
    if ((i = write(1, buff+wrote, len-wrote)) <= 0) {
      return(i);
    }
    wrote += i;
  } while (wrote<len);
  return(len);
}
```

The actual thumbnail generating piece

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wand/MagickWand.h>

#define ThrowWandException(wand, ret) \
{ \
  char \
    *description; \
 \
  ExceptionType \
    severity; \
 \
  description=MagickGetException(wand,&severity); \
  (void) fprintf(stderr,"%s %s %lu %s\n",GetMagickModule(),description); \
  description=(char *) MagickRelinquishMemory(description); \
  wand=DestroyMagickWand(wand); \
  MagickWandTerminus(); \
  return ret; \
}

int thumbnail (char *image_name, char *thumbnail_name){

  MagickWand *magick_wand;
  MagickBooleanType status;

  /* Read an image. */
  MagickWandGenesis();
  magick_wand=NewMagickWand();
  status=MagickReadImage(magick_wand, image_name);
  if (status == MagickFalse) ThrowWandException(magick_wand, 1);

  /* Turn the images into a thumbnail sequence. */
  MagickResetIterator(magick_wand);
  while (MagickNextImage(magick_wand) != MagickFalse)
    MagickResizeImage(magick_wand,106,80,LanczosFilter,1.0);

  /* Write the image then destroy it. */
  status=MagickWriteImages(magick_wand, thumbnail_name, MagickTrue);
  if (status == MagickFalse) ThrowWandException(magick_wand, 2);
  magick_wand=DestroyMagickWand(magick_wand);
  MagickWandTerminus();

  return 0;
}
```

Finally, `int main` and thumbnail path handling:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

int read_cmd(byte *buff);
int write_cmd(byte *buff, int len);

char *chop_path(char *orig) {
  char buf[PATH_MAX + 1];
  char *res, *dname, *thumb;

  res = realpath(orig, buf);
  if (res) {
    dname = dirname(res);
    thumb = strcat(dname, "/thumbnail.png");
    return thumb;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(){
  int result, i, len;
  byte buff[255];
  char *thumb;

  while (read_cmd(buff) > 0) {
    thumb = chop_path(buff);
    result = thumbnail(buff, thumb);

    buff[0] = result;
    write_cmd(buff, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using several files to implement this, you need a header file to
hold the prototypes of external functions (`read_cmd` etc) and types (`typedef
unsigned char byte;`)

In `read_exact` and `write_exact`, a `do .. while` loop is inappropriate.  A
`for` loop would be better.

```
for (int n, got = 0; got < len; got += n) {
    if ((n = read(0, buff+got, len-got)) <= 0) {
        return n;
    }
}
```

But I'm wondering about the need for a loop and the use of raw I/O (as opposed
to buffered).  It might be easier to use buffered I/O and treat what is
exchanged as strings.  There would be no need to prepend a size, just send a
string terminated by \n.  When using raw I/O, your `while` loop handles
the case when the `read` call does not read the complete block.  Since you are
not reading from a file that is correct, but the corollary of that is that you
should handle errors returned by `read`.   For example EINTR should probably
be handled.

Also is is better to use `fileno(stdin)`, `fileno(stdout)` instead of 0 and 1.

In `chop_path` you have concatenated the filename "/thumbnail.png" onto the
internal buffer returned by `dirname`.  In doing so you have written to a
buffer that should be considered `const` - you can't be sure there is space at
the end of the string.   Also you return 0 from `chop_path` on error but
`main` does not check for this.

On programming style, it is normally best to define variables at the point of
first use, where possible.  Also, variables should be defined one per line.